# Aspose.Words save Word document as pdf loses formatting

Tags: asp.net-core, aspose, aspose.words

I am using Aspose.Words for .NET to replace some merge fields in my document and then save the file as a PDF, however, my formatting is getting messed up (even for non-merge fields) by the conversion to PDF (refer to the images). The code is quite simple so I don't see what I'm missing.

The word document, pre-processing:
[image]

The generated pdf:
[image]

As you can see some of the fields are indented a bit more instead of being nicely aligned.

My code for generating the PDF and replacing the merge fields is:

```
    public async Task<Stream> GenerateContractAsync(string requestRegistrationId)
    {
        var requestRegistration = await _requestRegistrationRepository
            .FindRequestRegistration(requestRegistrationId)
            .Include(rr => rr.Request.QualityType)
            .Include(rr => rr.User)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        var file = await _fileService
            .LoadFileAsync("Concept contract.docx");

        var user = requestRegistration.User;

        var document = new Aspose.Words.Document(file);
        document.MailMerge.Execute(
            new[]
            {
                "EmployeeName", "EmployeeDateOfBirth", "EmployeePlaceOfBirth", "EmployeeSSN", "EmployeeCity",
                "EmployeeAddress", "ContractStartDate", "EmployeeFunction", "HourlyWage", "WageDeductionApplied"
            },
            new object[]
            {
                user.FullName, $"{user.Birthday:dd-MM-yyyy}", "Oss", user.Bsn, user.City,
                $"{user.PostalCode}, {user.City}", $"{requestRegistration.Request.StartDate:dd-MM-yyyy}",
                requestRegistration.Request.QualityType.Name, $"{requestRegistration.Request.HourlyRate:C}",
                user.PayrollTaxDiscountEnabled ? "Ja" : "Nee"
            }
        );

        var mergedDocumentStream = new MemoryStream();
        document.Save(mergedDocumentStream, SaveFormat.Pdf);

        #if DEBUG
        mergedDocumentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await _fileService.SaveFileToDiskAsync($"{user.Id}-{DateTimeOffset.Now:g}.pdf", "", mergedDocumentStream);
        #endif

        mergedDocumentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return mergedDocumentStream;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [latest version of Aspose.Words for .NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/) 18.8? In case the problem still remains, please ZIP and Upload your 1) input Word document 2) Aspose.Words 18.8 generated output file showing the undesired behavior and 3) simple console application (_source code without compilation errors_) to Dropbox and share the Download link here for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez Thank you for your response. I have created this ZIP for you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jsxytfnkm07h26/AsposeWordsDemo.zip?dl=0 - it contains the input document (`ExampleDocument.docx`), the generated output file (`merged.pdf`) and the console application (`Program.cs`).

Comment: The problem occurs because of missing fonts. Please refer to [this article](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/True+Type+Fonts) for details. In your case, please install 'Verdana', 'Arial' and 'Cambria' fonts on the machine where you are executing this Aspose.Words' code. Simply copying these font files from Windows machine to other machine may work. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez thank you for your response. I have just confirmed that it indeed is a problem with missing fonts on my Mac. Since the application I'm building will eventually be running on Windows that means there's no problem to fix. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because of missing fonts. Please refer to the following article for details.

[How Aspose.Words Uses True Type Fonts](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/True+Type+Fonts)

In your case, you need to install 'Verdana', 'Arial' and 'Cambria' fonts on the machine where you are executing this Aspose.Words' code. Simply copying these font files from Windows machine to other MAC machine should work.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.